# C++ code sometimes exits with 0xC0000005 error and sometimes executes, but fills array with random integers

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, depth-first-search, allocation

I am learning c++ after java and have written a program to solve a certain game with dfs. The issue is when run, sometimes the program doesn't execute and gives a 0xC0000005 error, but sometimes runs smoothly but fills the state array with random values. I assume that it has something to do with c++ memory allocation which I screwed up because idk what I'm doing

Here is the code (assume that data was declared to some array containing 0s, 1s, 2s, and 3s):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stack>

void printArray(int arr[][7])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << ", ";
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

bool solution (int arr[][7])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            if (arr[i][j] == 0)
                return false;
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int data[7][7];
    printArray(data);
    stack<int(*)[7][7]> nodes;//stack of each possible gamestate
    nodes.push(&data);
    while (nodes.size() > 0)
    {
       int (*statePtr)[7][7] = nodes.top();//accessing top element as pointer
       nodes.pop();
       int state[7][7];
       for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)//passing into 2d array by value
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            state [i][j] = (*statePtr[i][j]);
       if (solution(state))
       {
        printArray(state);
        break;
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)//for all empty values in state
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            if (state[i][j] == 0)
            {
                bool existNeigh1, existNeigh2, existNeigh3;
                existNeigh2 = false;
                existNeigh3 = false;
                int neighbors[8][2] = {
                {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}, 
                {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}};
                for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++)//checking if this cell has a 1, 3, 5 neighbor
                    {
                        if (i+neighbors[n][0] >= 0 && i+neighbors[n][0] < 7 && j+neighbors[n][1] >= 0 && j+neighbors[n][1] < 7)
                        {
                            int neighborValue = state[i+neighbors[n][0]][j+neighbors[n][1]];
                            if (neighborValue == 1)
                                existNeigh1 = true;
                            if (neighborValue == 2)
                                existNeigh2 = true;
                            if (neighborValue == 3)
                                existNeigh3 = true;
                        }
                    }
                if (existNeigh1)//if so, adding an updated board to the stack
                {
                    int stateCopy[7][7];
                    for(int r = 0; r < 7; r++)
                        for(int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
                            stateCopy[r][c] = state[r][c];
                    stateCopy[i][j] = 1;
                    nodes.push(&stateCopy);
                    //printArray(stateCopy);
                }
                if (existNeigh2)
                {
                    int stateCopy[7][7];
                    for(int r = 0; r < 7; r++)
                        for(int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
                            stateCopy[r][c] = state[r][c];
                    stateCopy[i][j] = 2;
                    nodes.push(&stateCopy);
                    //printArray(stateCopy);
                }
                if (existNeigh3)
                {
                    int stateCopy[7][7];
                    for(int r = 0; r < 7; r++)
                        for(int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
                            stateCopy[r][c] = state[r][c];
                    stateCopy[i][j] = 3;
                    nodes.push(&stateCopy);
                    //printArray(stateCopy);
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `nodes.push(&stateCopy);` - this pointer becomes dangling almost immediately, when `stateCopy` goes out of scope. Then accessing it is undefined behavior. You want `std::stack<std::array<std::array<int, 7>, 7>>`, and elsewhere use `std::array<std::array<int, 7>, 7>` instead of the regular arrays. Those can be copied with a single `=` (without a loop).

Comment: RIght.  Expanding just a bit, your `stateCopy` is a stack variable, and because of the way your code is written, they're probably all at the same stack offset.  You then save that stack address in your `std::stack`, which results in nonsense when the stack is used for other things.

Comment: Alr so I'll rewrite the code using std array then. If I'm understanding correctly, the problem is that I'm storing a pointer to stateCopy in the stack but once the if statement ends stateCopy goes out of scope which makes the pointer point nowhere? Also theoretically if I were to rewrite this without stf array, what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Local variables on the stack must be explicitly initialized. Try

```
in data[7][7] = {0};
```

which will initialize all 49 elements to 0.

Comment: True but irrelevant.  That's not the flaw here.